# `PowerShell.Create()` returning null

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, .net-standard

Added reference: `PowerShellStandard.Library`

Repro inside a default `.net-core` project:

```
// ...

using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

// ...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Collection<PSObject> output;
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddScript("$test = Get-Date; $test");
        output = ps.Invoke();
    }

// ...
```

I've tried it with or without the `using` block, but I end up with the same result: the `Create` method is *not* creating a `PowerShell` object, but it's also *not throwing an exception*.

Is this a common issue with the `PowerShell` `.net-standard` library?  Is there a workaround or another way to solve my problem?

*Additional info*, this is also happening with the `RunspaceFactory` class `CreateRunspace` method as I was exploring a workaround with managing runspaces myself.

Comment: What happens if you run the same code portion (compiled for net core) from command line as regular user?

Comment: @ZorgoZ The same result when building a .net core console application (if that's what you meant?).

Comment: That was what I meant. Then my presumption related to permissions seems wrong. Sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the source of the PowerShellStandard Library I noticed the following lines:

```
public static System.Management.Automation.PowerShell Create ( System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState initialSessionState ) { return default(System.Management.Automation.PowerShell); }
public static System.Management.Automation.PowerShell Create (  ) { return default(System.Management.Automation.PowerShell); }
public static System.Management.Automation.PowerShell Create ( System.Management.Automation.RunspaceMode runspace ) { return default(System.Management.Automation.PowerShell); }
```

Those will **always** return the `default` of the sealed PowerShell class and that will **always** be `null`.

This makes it that PowerShell isn't (fully) supported in PowerShellStandard Library 5.1.

Same is for `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace`.

Comment: `PowerShellStandard.Library` is a library targeting `.net-standard2` so it should work across all .net implementations (for powershell 5 and 6).  Give me a bit to test your suggestion.

Comment: Realized you're trying to re-target to powershell 6; this is not an answer to my problem case.

Comment: .net core doesn't need to, because the implementation is .net standard, so it *is* supported.  [Here's a related article from the official powershell github](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/cmdlet-example/command-line-simple-example.md).  It's possible to create multi-platform cmdlets using the library, but unable to use the other features (such as `PowerShell` and `RunspaceFactory`)

Comment: That is some terrible news. Looks like I will need to pursue another option (like using core apis). Thank you

Comment: Posted a question to the team https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellStandard/issues/46

Answer (score 7):

PowerShellStandard is a reference library, it's intended for projects that will be loaded into the same `AppDomain` as PowerShell. In those scenarios the required assemblies are already loaded, so it would be a waste to pull down the entire SDK.

In order to host PowerShell (or otherwise use PowerShell API's from outside a PowerShell session) you need to reference the PowerShell SDK (for PowerShell Core) or the GAC assemblies (for Windows PowerShell).

<s>To reference the SDK, you need a `nuget.config` file in the base directory of your project that adds the PowerShell myget as a source.  Here's an example</s>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-core" value="https://www.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="powershell-core" value="https://powershell.myget.org/F/powershell-core/api/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

And add a reference to the SDK in your csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.1.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

**Update 04/15/2021**

You don't need the nuget config anymore, the SDK is now available on nuget.

Comment: Just a note, I eventually figured this out and the MyGet repo is still broken; missing the wsman and diagnostics repos as dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the recently released [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK 6.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK).

It looks like it is designed for PowerShell hosting and related tasks.
At least the question like code worked fine in my .NET Core application.
This package reference is enough.