# Using Powershell in C# [.NET 6]

Tags: c#, powershell, migration, .net-6.0

I migrated from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.

```
System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
```

now returns null.

[image: Packages]

Is there a new package i need to reference or other solution?

Comment: This is happening because of a version of miss-match. Can please share the exception if any

Comment: Nevermind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733481/powershell-create-returning-null helped me.

Comment: At a minimum you need [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) (everything contained in that package is also included in the SDK)

Answer (score 3):

Removing the old References and adding the NuGet package
[`Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/) solved this issue.

Comment: An overview of all PowerShell SDK-related packages can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211901/45375).

Comment: Note, however, that the package you mention is for creating _stand-alone_ PowerShell (Core) applications, whereas the  [`PowerShellStandard.Library`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library/) package is for creating modules and PowerShell hosts that run _from within PowerShell_ - and the latter package is designed to work in PowerShell (Core) sessions too.

Comment: I wasted time trying to use the powershellstandard.library.  Because the SDK was so large and I was skeered to use it. This article may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733481/powershell-create-returning-null